# login using ajax and php always wrong password

Tags: php, ajax

I tried this code to use for login but it does not work. when I click on submit, nothing happens. When I tried to login I am always getting a wrong password error, but my password is correct. what should I do?

**my HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="loginform"   method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="userid" class="col-sm-3 control-label">User ID</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9 has-feedback">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userid" name="userid" placeholder="Enter Your User ID" required>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9 has-feedback">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" required>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8">
                            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </form>
```

**my Php**

```
 <?php
        $userid = security($_POST['userid']);
                $password = security($_POST['password']);

                $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE USER_USERNAME = '".$userid."' AND USER_PASSWORD = '".$password."'");
                $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                if ($numrows!==0) 
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                    {
                        @$_SESSION['session_userid'] = $row['USER_USERNAME'];
                        @$_SESSION['session_accounttype'] = $row['ACCESS_ID'];
                    }
                    //Location Depends on the User Type
                    if($_SESSION['session_accounttype']=="1")
                    {
                            echo 'true';
                    }
                    }
              else
                {
                    echo 'false';
                }
        ?>
```

**My JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_err").css('display', 'none', 'important');
     $("#submit").click(function(){
          username=$("#userid").val();
          password=$("#password").val();
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "../basefunction/login.php",
            data: "userid="+username+"&password="+password,
           success: function(html){    
            if(html=='true')    {
             //$("#add_err").html("right username or password");
             window.location="admin";
            }
            else    {
            $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
             $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/alert.png' />Wrong username or password");
            }
           },
           beforeSend:function()
           {
            $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
            $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...")
           }
          });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: SQL injection vulnerabilities, error suppression operators... When you debug this where specifically does it fail?  Are the values you expect being sent to the server?  Is the SQL query what you expect it to be?  What are the results of that query?  What is the actual response from the server?  Are there any errors in the response, or in the PHP logs?  You should also definitely check for errors from the SQL query after executing it.

Comment: Did you not `hash` your passowords? I thing you have an encoding issue, but you dont show all relavant code here, so i cant really tell!

Comment: i did not hash my password because its not necessary

Comment: Is this even going through the Ajax call? I mean you don't seem to have an e.preventDefault() to stop the form from submitting?

Comment: @ShermaineChaingan: Side note: Hashing user passwords *is* "necessary".  Storing user passwords in plain text is a ***very bad thing***.

Comment: @David i know sir but i only testing this function i will do it once its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why other answers talk the salt for password?question asks why password was wrong.
I think this code have questions
 if($_SESSION['session_accounttype']=="1")

The session_accounttype may be not eq 1?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment so... 
There is many problems with this example.

1. The submit button is going to submit your form automatically to "/". Look into preventdefault in javascript to solve that problem.
2. You are using ajax post with a query string. This would be done using the 'data' property in jquery data: {'userid' : username ,'password':password}. Then use $_POST['userid] and $_POST['password'] in php to get the values;
3. Sql inject will become a problem. But i can see you are learning and hope this is just a test to better your understanding of databasing.
4. Hash passwords

Comment: yes this is only a test i know how to prevent injection i just want to try ajax in login

Comment: @ShermaineChaingan: `"i know how to prevent injection"` - Then why aren't you doing that?  The problem could very well be that your SQL query is failing because of the injection vulnerability.  If you can eliminate a possible source of the problem, then do so and the problem itself may become moot.

Comment: I found the tutorial you are using. I suggest you try another. Possibly http://www.codingcage.com/2015/11/ajax-login-script-with-jquery-php-mysql.html However this one is using jquery validation which might be out of your scope.